# Better Way to Export Data from MS SQL server

Tags: powershell, sql-server, export

**[TL:DR]** I need to be able to export ad-hoc data from a MS SQL Server DB to a file on my local machine using a predetermined format with *Latin1 encoding. I wasn't sure if SSMS had a way to create a workflow, or if there were a PowerShell script solution, but I'm not able to use SSIS for various reasons unfortunately.

**The longer story**

I frequently extract data from a bunch of tables on various MS SQL Server instances, and all these instances are running various versions of SQL Server from 2008 up to the 2016 currently. Once I export the data I use it to build different test environments that are set up using SSIS packages.

I usually connect to the SQL Servers using SSMS 2016, and then I use the "Export Data" wizard. Due to the need of having to manually click on various options with this method, it's not very efficient and also human error is occurring with this task due to all the manual clicking aspects and mistakes are being made at this level and aren't noticed until the data is needed, analyzed, etc.

I'd like a way to make this process I've tried to explain more efficient and automate more for less manual human steps. I tried using a PowerShell (and SQLPS ) method and seems very slow and the encoding for the exported files wasn't ever really right. I work with old DB's and old SSIS packages, and converting all this to UTF8 seems very messy, so I absolutely need output in ANSI1252 (Latin 1) encoding.

Any experts out there with some good suggestions that would help me?

Comment: Well. Thanks for the downvote and all the constructive feedback. Real helpful..

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm not asking for help writing scripts, I even mention that I wrote the scripts but found performance and output encoding options of SQLPS to be lacking. *Even more TLDR summary:* SQLPS, bad encoding handling and slow. SMSS export wizard too many manual steps (mouse clicks). SSIS packages depend on write access to server and tight coupling to VS-version. What to do for _efficient_ (as in reusable, portable and quick to deploy export of tables with selectable encoding and good performance).

Comment: Have you tried BCP?  Performance wise this has been the best option for us.  Not sure if it can do the ANSI1252 encoding tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> export ad-hoc data from a MS SQL server to a file on my local machine,
>   using a pre-determined format with Latin1 encoding? SSIS is out (I
>   think) due to read-only servers and varying SQL server versions.

I'll say it again as mentioned in a comment... so check out the [BCP Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).

You mention [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode); and **BCP Utility** supports [Unicode Character Format to Export](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188289.aspx) so... look into using this method for your ***ad hoc extracts to a file on your local machine*** needs.

Additionally, don't forget about [COLLATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) since, if applicable, you could "**use the COLLATE clause to apply a character expression to a certain collation**" within the logic applied for the export query.

> ### [Import and Export Bulk Data by Using the bcp Utility (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx)
>
> This topic provides an overview for using the [bcp
>   utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to
>   export data from anywhere in a SQL Server database where a SELECT
>   statement works, including partitioned views
>
> The bcp utility (Bcp.exe) is a command-line tool that uses the Bulk
>   Copy Program (BCP) API. The bcp utility performs the following tasks:
>
> - Bulk exports data from a SQL Server table into a data file.
> - Bulk exports data from a query.
> - Bulk imports data from a data file into a SQL Server table.
> - Generates format files.
>
> The bcp utility is accessed by the **bcp** command. To use the **bcp**
>   command to bulk import data, you must understand the schema of the
>   table and the data types of its columns, unless you are using a
>   pre-existing format file.
>
> The bcp utility can export data from a SQL Server table to a data file
>   for use in other programs. The utility can also import data into a SQL
>   Server table from another program, usually another database management
>   system (DBMS). The data is first exported from the source program to a
>   data file and then, in a separate operation, copied from the data file
>   into a SQL Server table.
>
> The **bcp** command provides switches that you use to specify the data
>   type of the data file and other information. If these switches are not
>   specified, the command prompts for formatting information, such as the
>   type of data fields in a data file. The command then asks whether you
>   want to create a format file that contains your interactive responses.
>   If you want flexibility for future bulk-import or bulk-export
>   operations, a format file is often useful. You can specify the format
>   file on later **bcp** commands for equivalent data files. For more
>   information, see [Specify Data Formats for Compatibility when Using
>   bcp (SQL
>   Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190759.aspx).
>
> **Note!!** The bcp utility is written by using the ODBC bulk-copy. For a description of the bcp command syntax, see bcp Utility.
>
> ### Examples
>
> For **bcp** examples, see:
>
> - [bcp Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)
> - [Create a Format File (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191516.aspx)
> - [Examples of Bulk Import and Export of XML Documents (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184.aspx)
> - [Keep Identity Values When Bulk Importing Data (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186335.aspx)
> - [Keep Nulls or Use Default Values During Bulk Import (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187887.aspx)
> - [Specify Field and Row Terminators (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485.aspx)
> - [Use a Format File to Bulk Import Data (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178129.aspx)
> - [Use Character Format to Import or Export Data (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190919.aspx)
> - [Use Native Format to Import or Export Data (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191232.aspx)
> - [Use Unicode Character Format to Import or Export Data (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188289.aspx)
> - [Use Unicode Native Format to Import or Export Data (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189941.aspx)
>
> <sub>[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx)</sub>

Comment: Bcp seems to be exactly the tool I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Afternoon,

Not sure if its of much help - but I've always found using .net objects fairly solid when working with SQL.  Something like this works well for me:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = "Connection_String_Goes_Here"
$conn.open()

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.connection = $conn

$cmd.commandtext = "SELECT * FROM myTable"

$sqlResults = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

$sqlResults | Get-Member

if ($sqlResults.HasRows -eq $true) {
    while ($sqlResults.read()) {
        $sqlResults.GetValue(1)
    }
} else {
    "No Results"
}

$conn.Close()
```